# awscrt python module throwing 'undefined symbol: EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13' error in ARM yocto

Tags: python, pip, openssl, aws-iot, evp-cipher

I have a custom ARM gateway on which I am trying to run a greengrass v2 component. This requires python awsiotsdk. But when I import the awsiotsdk I am getting this error:

`ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_awscrt.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabi.so: undefined symbol: EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13`

When I ran the same component in an x86 environment  with the same awsiotsdk version, I did not get the error.

This is the difference I noticed:

ARM GATEWAY

```
bash-5.0# strings   /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_awscrt.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabi.so    | grep -i EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13
    bash-5.0#
```

X86 LAPTOP

```
    bash-4.2# strings   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/_awscrt.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so    | grep -i EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_storage
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_once_bss_get
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_storage_bss_get
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_do_init
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_init
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_once
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_init
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_storage
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13_once
    EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13
    bash-4.2#
```

Btw the awscrt module in the gateway was compiled during the "pip install" step. So I thought maybe it has to do with  openssl?  Maybe the gateway does not not support TLS1.3. But it looks like the gateway does support TLS1.3 .

```
bash-5.0# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
bash-5.0#
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: `EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13` looks like an OpenSSL thing but actually isn't. OpenSSL defines numerous `EVP_*` functions but this one does not exist. Some google searching suggests this might be a BoringSSL thing instead (BoringSSL is a fork of OpenSSL)

Comment: Thats very strange. It doesnt look lile awscrt code references EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13. Maybe this dependency is introduced during build on the Gateway. Not sure how to confirm. Dont think yocto OS has boringssl

Answer (score 0):

I could confirm that symbols like "EVP_aead_aes_128_gcm_tls13" is part of the "awscrt" python module and they are [taken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/common-runtime.html) from boringssl project.

In my case somehow the "setup.py" build from inside the gateway failed to include this functionality. But when I built awscrt with the yocto cross-toolchain in my laptop, it worked.